# JMeter - use a variable in another variable

Tags: performance, variables, jmeter, performance-testing

I have to do the following i have a User Defined Variable in Jmeter its value is basicly an XML and i need to assign some variables inside this variables value. I have done the following - `<bbc:CorrelationID>${ID}</bbc:CorrelationID>      <bbc:MessageID>${ID}</bbc:MessageID>` where ID is a Random Variable element but when i run the script it does not place those values inside the variable value.

How do i reference the random variable in the value of another variable?

Side note: It seems to proccess functions if i place them inside the value but not other variables. So another solution will be to figure out a function that will give me a unique String that is the same in both MessageID and CorrelationID(MID and CID must be the same) and be different in every sample. (__Random does not work since the MesgID and CorID will differ from one another).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap this variable into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval), this way JMeter will automatically resolve and evaluate all nested functions and/or variable in the input entity.

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: God bless you good sir! __eval was the function that i needed thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

[__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)  is exactly what you need

> This can be used to evaluate nested variable references

In your case

```
 ${__V(<bbc:CorrelationID>${ID}</bbc:CorrelationID> <bbc:MessageID>${ID}</bbc:MessageID> )}
```

ID will have the same vale in both tags.

Answer (score 0):

Using _eval when using the variable solved the problem for me since i was using it in another function that encodes to base64 this is how the final function looked for me - ${__base64Encode(${__eval(${req})})} - the variable i needed to change in question was "req".